# Storing multiple number ranges in json for later lookup

Tags: json, neo4j

I'm trying to find a good way to store multiple ranges of numbers and single digits within a json array that I can later lookup in a graph database (likely neo4j).

So numbers and ranges such as

1
5-12
25-99

and later on if I want to see if number 27 is in there, that I can.  What's the best way to structure this in a json string and is it possible to use neo4j to check if number 27 is within one of the the ranges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this is to use a `Range` node for each numeric range.

For example:

```
(:Range {min: 1, max: 1})
(:Range {min: 5, max: 12})
(:Range {min: 25, max: 99})
```

And here is an example of how you could find all `Foo` nodes that have a range that includes 27:

```
MATCH (n:Foo)-[:HAS_RANGE]->(r:Range)
WHERE r.min <= 27 <= r.max
RETURN n;
```